# How to set type for Apollo resolver context?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo

I have a simple Apollo GraphQL subgraph where I want to set the type for my context arg in my resolvers.

I create a resolver and set the type for context as follows:

```js
interface Context {
  dataSources: {
    shopify: Shopify;
  }
}

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema: buildSubgraphSchema({ 
    typeDefs,
    resolvers: {
      Query: {
        shop(_, _args, ctx: Context) {
          console.log("ctx:", ctx)
        },
      }
    }
  }),
  dataSources: () => ({
    shopify: new Shopify()
  })
});
```

However, it appears the `Context` interface I am setting is incompatible with the type my resolver expects and I get the following error:

```
Argument of type '{ typeDefs: any; resolvers: { Query: { shop(_: any, _args: any, ctx: Context): void; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DocumentNode | (GraphQLSchemaModule | DocumentNode)[] | LegacySchemaModule'.
  Types of property 'resolvers' are incompatible.
    Property 'Query' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type '{ shop(_: any, _args: any, ctx: Context): void; }' is not assignable to type 'GraphQLScalarType<unknown, unknown> | { [enumValue: string]: string | number; } | { [fieldName: string]: GraphQLFieldResolver<any, unknown, any, unknown> | { requires?: string | undefined; resolve: GraphQLFieldResolver<...>; }; }'.
        Types of property 'shop' are incompatible.
          Type '(_: any, _args: any, ctx: Context) => void' is not assignable to type 'string | number | GraphQLFieldResolver<any, unknown, any, unknown> | { requires?: string | undefined; resolve: GraphQLFieldResolver<any, unknown, any, unknown>; } | undefined'.
            Type '(_: any, _args: any, ctx: Context) => void' is not assignable to type 'GraphQLFieldResolver<any, unknown, any, unknown>'.
              Types of parameters 'ctx' and 'context' are incompatible.
                Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Context'.ts(2345)
```

How can I set the context type for my resolver so I can get access to the interface and datasources etc?

Answer (score 1):

OK I think I found a better solution.

First things first lets really understand what `buildSubgraphSchema` can accept:

```js
buildSubgraphSchema(
  modulesOrSDL:
    | (GraphQLSchemaModule | DocumentNode)[] //interesting...
    | DocumentNode
    | LegacySchemaModule, //our tried and true way
): GraphQLSchema
```

The problem is we are trying to pass in a `LegacySchemaModule` (`{typeDefs, resolvers}`) but due to the `<unknown>` generic being passed in to the `GraphQLResovlerMap` creates a conflict with an explicitly defined `Context`

```js
type LegacySchemaModule = {
  typeDefs: DocumentNode | DocumentNode[];
  resolvers?: GraphQLResolverMap<unknown>; //note `unknown`, the root of our typing errors
};
```

What we need to use in to actually act on context within the resolver is a `GraphQLSchemaModule` defined as follows:

```js
export interface GraphQLSchemaModule {
  typeDefs: DocumentNode;
  resolvers?: GraphQLResolverMap<any>; //note the `any` here
}
```

So with a resolver defined like this:

```js
export const resolvers: GraphQLResolverMap<Context> = {
  Query: {
    shop(_, _args, ctx) {
      console.log(ctx.datasources.shopify); // Shopify
    },
  },
};
```

We can now pass in an array of `(GraphQLSchemaModule | DocumentNode)[]`:

```js
const server = new ApolloServer({ 
    schema: buildSubgraphSchema([ //note the array
      {
        typeDefs, //DocumentNode
        resolvers, //GraphQLSchemaModule, in this case GraphQLResolverMap<Context>
      },
    ]),
  });
```

That worked for me, no ts errors and the server started up great.  Open to suggestions though from the community as to better patterns here.

Ultimately I think codegen tools are designed to solve alot of these problems.  I'm diving into this now: https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

The `ApolloServer` class is generic, you should specify your custom context as a type parameter. See [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/context) and [these unit tests](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/7ff96f5331fbf14c0a25094007f6f05e799ee052/packages/server/src/__tests__/standalone/standaloneSpecific.test.ts).

```
interface Context {
  dataSources: {
    shopify: Shopify;
  }
}

const server = new ApolloServer<Context>({
//                             ^^^^^^^^^
  schema: buildSubgraphSchema({ 
    typeDefs,
    resolvers: {
      Query: {
        shop(_, _args, ctx: Context) {
          console.log("ctx:", ctx)
        },
      }
    }
  }),
  dataSources: () => ({
    shopify: new Shopify()
  })
});
```